# objective-c empty NSArray error

Tags: objective-c, json, ios4, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm using JSON to parse data into an NSArray 'courseArray'. I then filter this data using NSPredicate and store it into 'rows'. The problem is, i dont know how to determine if 'rows' is empty or not. For example : If a record exists, rows will contain the appropriate objects, but if the record doesnt exist then the application crashes (also when i use NSLog to see the contents of the array its blank, i believe its supposed to say its nil? if there are no objects). How can i fix this?

```
if (dict)
{
    courseArray  = [[dict objectForKey:@"lab"] retain];
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"labNumber== %@",labSelected]; //filter
    rows = [[courseArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]retain];
}

[jsonreturn release];

self.formattedTextView.opaque = NO;
self.formattedTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

NSLog(@"array %@",rows);

 **NSDictionary *currentSelection = [rows objectAtIndex:0];** (app crashes at this line - [NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array')
 NSString *labNumber = [currentSelection objectForKey:@"labNumber"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if([courseArray count] > 0)` also another method that can be of help here is

`[courseArray containsObject:(id)]`

Answer (score 2):

`-objectAtIndex:` will raise an exception if there is no object at the nominated index. If `rows` is empty there won't be an object at index 0, hence the exception. As you don't catch the exception, the result is that your app is terminated.

You probably want to compare `[rows count]` to 0 to check that there's something in it and to react appropriately if not.

Comment: I figured that much but im not sure on how to stop the error i have tried if([rows count]==0) but it doesnt work, also tried "if(rows!=nil)

Comment: Your app can't still be raising an exception at the `[rows objectForIndex:0]` line if you've wrapped it so that you never get to it unless `[rows count]` is non-zero. Is it possible some other typo or minor flaw confused the issue?